# How to replace a column in dataframe for the result of a function

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

currently I have a dataframe with a column named age, which has the age of the person in days. I would like to convert this value to year, how could I achieve that?
at this moment, if one runs this command

```
df['age']
```

the result would be something like

```
0        18393
1        20228
2        18857
3        17623
4        17474
5        21914
6        22113
7        22584
8        17668
9        19834
10       22530
11       18815
12       14791
13       19809
```

I would like to change the value from each row to the current value/ 365 (which would convert days to year)

Comment: did you try: `df["age"] / 365`

Comment: ````df['age']/=365````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested:

```
>>> df['age'] / 365
         age
0  50.391781
1  55.419178
2  51.663014
3  48.282192
4  47.873973
```

Or if you need a real year:

```
>>> df['age'] // 365
   age
0   50
1   55
2   51
3   48
4   47
```